# DDR3 RAM and speeds

Tags: memory, ddr3

I bought some computer parts to build my first system. The mobo was DOA and I RMAed it. They were supposed to send me a replacement but instead just refunded the money on CC. Um, ok, but I still need a mobo! So I decided I want to get a different mobo instead. I was looking at them and one I'm interested in says "Memory Standard: DDR3 2200/1333/1066/800." but the RAM I bought is DDR3 1600Mhz. Can I still use it with this mobo just at lower speeds? Since shipping and RMAing the board took forever I don't want to send another board back. If the processor matters I got a Core i7-920.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I have DDR3 1600 which is running just fine at 1333.  Including running a full set of memory tests for an extended period (3 or 4 days) when I built the system.

Comment: Did you have to do anything special to get it to work or does it automatically run at 1333 "out of the box?"

Comment: @urs1: Right out of the box.  1333 is what my mobo set it as based on the information programmed into the chips; the mobo only supports 1600 DDR3 as an "overclocking" option.

Answer (score 0):

What motherboard is it that you bought? because the site may have missed the number 1600 when filling in specification. Generally boards that support something at 800 up to 2200 mhz will support most ranges in between. It can end up running at a slightly lower speed but it should still work.

Comment: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128423